# laravel 5 validation message return some array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im working on validation in laravel so below is my code

```
//error holder
                $error = array();
                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
                    'email' => 'email|unique:users',
                    'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([-.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$/',
                    'new_password' => 'required',
                    'confirm_password' => 'required',
                    'full_name' => 'required',
                    'role' => 'required',
                    'status' => 'required',
                ]);
                if ($validator->fails()){ 
                    array_push($error, $validator->messages());
                }
$msg = "Ops seems like there's an error: ";
                    foreach($error as $error_bug){
                        $msg .= $error_bug . ", ";
                    }

//return error
return $msg;
```

so first i created an empty array then next push the error message unto the array and loop through the array of objects and return it to the client. Everything works except there's an ugly thing going, it render me this

> Ops seems like there's an error: {"email":["The email has already been taken."]}

as you can see there's bracket and braces which I dont want, i only want to get the message of the error from the validation fail. Any ideas, help?

Comment: Can you `print_r($error);`and `print_r($error_bug);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (count($errors) > 0) <div class="alert alert-danger">
<ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
<li><b>Ops, something went wrong.</b></li>
<li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul> </div> @endif
```

The advantage of this method is that you don't repeat unnecessary code.

UPDATE:

```
$msg = $validator->errors()->all("Ops seems like there's an error: :message");
```

Comment: im retrieving it in ajax way so I want only the message to be thrown back

Comment: Updated my answer, checked the code with laravel and it worked :)